# Visual Studio for Mac Browser .Net Core code from SourceLink

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I don't know if this feature is existing or not on vs for Mac but I'm asking myself if it's possible to browser .Net 6 source code when navigating through implementation of specific object or method when I'm not in debug mode just like I do In standard visual studio.
Currently on Mac I'm able to see the assembly explorer, but it doesn't contain methods content for example for WebApplication.CreateBuilder method all I get is:

[image]

In standard visual studio I'm able to browser .Net source code using SourceLink like this:

[image]

Is this feature is even enable in vs for Mac ? If it is do you know how to enable it, I already enabled source link for nuget packages and I'm able to browse source code of libraries like Newtonsoft.Json in assembly explorer.

Answer (score 0):

The Assembly Viewer in your case will be showing the reference assembly which will not have any implementation. If you find the assembly that has the implementation you can drag that dll or open it in Visual Studio for Mac.

By default Visual Studio for Mac opens the ASP.NET Core reference assemblies from:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/
```

Instead you can open the assemblies from this other folder which has the full implementation:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/
```

An alternative way is to step into the .NET code when you are debugging.

In order to step into .NET code you need to enable the Microsoft symbol server. In **Preferences** - **Debugger** - **Symbol Servers**, check **Use Microsoft Symbol server**

[image: Preferences - Debugger- Symbol Servers]

Then you should be able to step into .NET Code.

Note that this can make debugging slower since the symbols need to be downloaded from the symbol server, at least until the symbols are cached.

[image: Stepping into System.Console.WriteLine]